How to enable OpenSSL legacy in Google App Engine
In the latest version of Google App Engine, the legacy version of OpenSSL is disabled. I would like to understand if there is any way to enable it.
I'm using Google App Engine standard with PHP 8.3.
The last version with PHP 8.2 was working correctly. I would like to understand if there is any way to enable it.
